# Which is correct, "opt out of" or "opt out from" and why?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct, *opt out of* or *opt out from* and why?

Eg. This customer has opted out **of** this programme OR This customer has opted out **from** this programme

Both prepositions are used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opt-out):

- > Google suggested the creation of a unified approach for opting-out from taking part in Wi-Fi-based positioning systems.
- > People are able to opt out of receiving any offers from U.S. national credit bureaus.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to show what you've found already, why you think that one might be more "correct" than the other, and what shade of meaning you want. This is not really different from "they moved out of/from the neighborhood" or "he drove out of/from the city"

Comment: FYI--"of" is much more common than "from": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opt+out+of%2Copt+out+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=0&case_insensitive=true

Comment: Note that 'opting out' should not be hyphenated.

Comment: Also note that "[opt out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/opt-out)" can be a noun phrase ("There is an opt-out for these employees from the requirement to have health coverage") as well as a verb, and it's quite possible they might take different prepositions.